# Can I use the past perfect with present perfect in English

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, british-english, learning

Is it correct to to use past perfect with present perfect as below

> He has informed me that you had approved his request for a loan.

Please clarify. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some common combinations of tense constructions in consecutive clauses. But there is no rule that prohibits the past perfect in a clause following a clause containing a present perfect. Indeed, just about any consecutive clauses can contain any verb construction.

In your case, the most likely context suggests the present perfect in both clauses:

> He *has* informed me that you *have* approved his request for a loan.

But the past perfect is feasible in the following context:

> He *has* informed me that you *had* approved his request for a loan,
>   but changed your mind the following day.

This is a typical use of the past perfect to indicate the *past in the past*.

Comment: Thank you, so instead: can I put is as: He informed that you had approved his request for a loan.

Comment: My other doubt is whether using present perfect is correct in this context? Can you please clarify. . So which is correct : he has informed or he informed.

Comment: Yes, depending on the context, you could say _He informed me that you *had* approved his request for a loan_. But _He informed me that you *have* approved his request for a loan_ is also possible. Whether you need _informed_ or _has informed_ is a different issue. There is no short answer here. I suggest you read this excellent post on the present perfect (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) and/or ask a separate question on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. I think the present perfect tense goes with the present simple tense to describe something in the past that relates/connects to the present time.

The past perfect tense should go with the past simple tense with the sense that something else had been done/said/finished before a certain point of time in the past.